# Convert MADX script to Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I want to run a simulation in Python which is written in [madx](http://mad.web.cern.ch/mad/)
I am asking if their is a possible method to convert a MADX script to Python ?

Comment: Could you share the script, maybe you could convert it manually.

Comment: @Nineteendo Thank you for the answer, its very long simulation script importing many other files and modules so i was looking for a direct method and make it easier to convert.

Comment: What is MADX?  Searching shows several possibilities.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Its the MAD - Methodical Accelerator Design its writen mainly in C++ / Fortran

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you mean by converting it to python. But I found a module that might help you interact with your MADX files: https://pypi.org/project/madplot/

What I've been doing, is I just have my python script call on os.system():

```
def runMADX(madxFile, outFile="out.txt"):
    """
    Runs madx.exe with .madx file and pipes console output to output file
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    madxFile:        filename of a MADX .madx file to be used for running MADX
    outFile:         filename to be used for storing MADX console output. Defaults to "out.txt".
    """
    cmd = "madx.exe " + madxFile + " > " + outFile
    os.system(cmd)
```